# Android list only my drawables

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a spinner with all the drawables in my app. I'm using

```
Field[] images = R.drawable.class.getFields();
```

to do that, but that lists all of the drawables including all of Android's default drawables, so I get something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1glfd.png

Is there a way to filter out Android's default drawables without doing it manually with a hard-coded list of them?

Answer (score 1):

getDeclaredFields() is the answer